# How to build a table?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

This might sound non-rational, but I want to build a table on Tizen Wearable (for my watch).

It still has Tizen 4.0 version, so I'm interested in a solution which is capable running on that OS.

I have looked at `gengrid`: https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/wearable/component-gengrid/ but at the bottom it says it has a dependency of

> Tizen 6.0 and Higher for Wearable

So, do I have any other option for having a grid beside creating my own with `box` of `boxes` which seems very uneffective?

My intention is to create a (not so large) table with text items. I'm planning it to be pannable, just like a website in the browser:

- rotary or pinch: zoom in-out
- touch drag: pan

Do anyone know any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be panning in your view, you need to use scroller.
so create one scroller in the window,
and add table as content of this scroller.

table has good example here.
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/container-table/

of cause this is not gengrid, it cannot lazy-loading and recycling items.
if you need lazy-loading and recycling features to display many elements,
you might have to use genlist full-style and put the box or table in each items.

pinch-zoom is very difficult to implement for general ui-object unlikely web-browser.
in EFL, there is animation helper named elm_transit,
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/elementary-animation/
see the zoom effect.

and gesture layer class.
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/touch-gesture/
see the zoom gesture.

you need to mix these two helper classes to implement pinch-zoom effect.
i hope this answer is helpful.